# Eclipse color themes not working

Tags: eclipse

I have followed the clear instructions to install Eclipse Color Themes 1.0.0 in Eclipse Luna 4.4.0, Ubuntu 10.04.2 64Bits, and whenever I check any of the themes:

1. No preview is shown.
2. The theme is not applied when I click apply and accept.

I have checked other questions such as:
[How can I change Eclipse theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937825/how-can-i-change-eclipse-theme)
[Eclipse Color Theme is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553444/eclipse-color-theme-is-not-working)
but those are not my problems. I get no errors.

Update: It turns out that the editor is working, but the rest of the windows are with their original aspect.

Any advice is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried restarting Eclipse after changing the theme?

Comment: After more searching I have discovered it is a known issue: https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme/issues/73

Comment: I recommend answering your own question. Post that link and an explanation so anyone else searching for this problem can easily understand what is going on.

Comment: Actually I voted to close it since I do not like to answer my own questions :) But I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: it is a known bug for that Eclipse version:
https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme/issues/73

Basically, you have to enable GTK3 when launching it, this can be done in the `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Luna
Exec=env SWT_GTK3=1 ~/Apps/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=~/Apps/eclipse/eclipse-1.png
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

And it also requires to set the Global Dark theme ON on Gnome Tweak tool.